# grep seems to ignore --include

Tags: grep

`man grep` says

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

. . .

   --include=GLOB
          Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
          matching as described under --exclude).
```

So I typed

```
grep --include="*.html" 'li' *
```

to search for instances of `li` in HTML files in the current directory.  Instead I get a list of every use of `li` anywhere in the directory, even in the non-HTML files.  What am I doing wrong?  I tried all kinds of variants like

```
grep --include=\*.html 'li' *
```

but without any luck.

Comment: 'grep 'li' *.html' try this

Comment: ' grep --include="*.html" 'li' * ' works for me please give your grep version using 'grep -version' command

Answer (score 4):

`--include=PATTERN` only works when you add `-r`

```
$ grep -r --include='*.html' 'li' .

-R, -r, --recursive   Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
--include=PATTERN     Recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN.
--exclude=PATTERN     Recurse in directories skip file matching PATTERN.
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell you're using (bash, tsh, zsh, etc) will dictate the commandline globbing that will and won't work. Most people use bash because it's installed by default on many distros - I use bash.

The following syntax has always worked for me.

```
    grep -r --include=*.html li *
```

1. As mentioned above, the -r switch allows grep to search
   subdirectories, otherwise it won't, which makes it look like the
   grep failed.
2. Simple file type inclusions (one extension) need no tweeking.
3. Don't quote (single or double) the inclusion, the parser doesn't like it

For inclusions of multiple extensions I use a bash brace expansion.

```
    grep -r --include=*.{html,htm,js} li *
```

Other things to try if you are still having trouble

1. Escape the * to protect it when it's parsed by the shell

   ```
   grep -r --include=\*.html li *
   ```
2. Make the search path more explicit

   ```
   grep -r --include=\*.html li ./*
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -version` doesn't work, but `grep --version` gives

```
grep (GNU grep) 2.9
```

and the copyright statement.

---

```
grep 'li' *.html
```

gets the shell to do the globbing, which isn't useful to me since I want to recurse.

---

I originally tried the command with `-R` (or `-r`) but that didn't work either.  The command recurses but brings up files without `html` in the name (or anywhere in the path).  So that's not it either.

---

I'd post these as comments or edit into the original but for some reason StackExchange isn't properly associating my account.  (Mods: please comment-ify this!)

Comment: is the find one is also not working???

Comment: @harish.venkat: I can't quite get it to work, but it seems the most promising at the moment.  I was working on a similar solution before I posted but couldn't get anywhere; this puts me closer.  But I'm still getting strange "No such file or directory" errors even though the output of find alone seems OK.  My actual string: `find . -name '*.html' | xargs grep -l 'li'`.

Comment: OK, adding -0 to `xargs` takes care of the file not found errors, now I just need some kind of `2>/dev/null` magic to stop the errors in `find`.

Comment: Also there's an `xargs: argument line too long` error; I don't imagine there's an easy fix to that?

Comment: @Charles You need to create an account on [unix.se] with the same openid that you used on [so] and associate your cookie-based account with it.

Answer (score 0):

`find $directoryname -maxdepth 1 -name '*.html' | xargs grep 'li'`
Here `-maxdepth 1` is for searching only in the directory and not its subdirectories. If you want to search even in sub directory remove `-maxdepth 1` in the command.

Comment: The same old error: you do not take into account filenames with spaces, where your command fails.